# Computing $P(X)$ from $P(X-X')$, where $X$ and $X'$ are iid

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, density-function

$X$ are $X'$ are two independent and identical distributed variables.

Given the distribution of $X-X'$, is the distribution of $X$ identifiable up to mean shift? If yes, how to compute it? If no, what can we know about $X$?

I can think of the equation

$$\forall c\in \mathbb{R}^+, F_{X-X'}(c) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x')\int_{-\infty}^{x'+c}f_X(x) \ dxdx',$$

where $F$ and $f$ denotes CDF and PDF respectively. But I don't know how to further solve $f_X$ from $F_{X-X'}$. It seems a convolution operation. Are there explicit solution expressions?

Comment: This probably requires the characteristic function since $$\phi_{X-X'}(t) = \phi_X(t) \phi_{-X'}(t) = \phi_X(t) \phi_{-X}(t) = \phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t).$$

Comment: From the comment of @SarveshRavichandranIyer, it seems it is impossible to retrieve $\mathbb{P}_X(x)$ from $\mathbb{P}_{X-X'}(x)$. Indeed, knowing $\mathbb{P}_X(x)$ is equivalent to knowning $\phi_X(t)$. And by denoting $g(t) = \ln(\phi_{X-X'}(t))$ and $f(t) = \ln (\phi_X(t))$, we have only the following equation: $$f(t) + f(-t) = g(t) \tag{*}$$ We cannot solve $(*)$ for $f(t)$.